# How to implement a two level DrawerLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, listview

I'm trying to implement a two level DrawerLayout. As a baseline, I'm using the Google planet example from http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html . So I'd like to extend this example, such that selecting a planet from the list of planets, replaces the planet list with a list of cities on that planet (mostly blank except for Earth - I'm still fleshing out my data :-) ).

I figured there are three approaches I could take:-

1. Replace the ListView
2. Keep the ListView, but replace its ArrayAdapter
3. Keep the ListView and the ArrayAdapter, but replace the adapter's data

So trying option 3 (is this the best approach?), in my DrawerItemClickListener I do the following ...

```
arrayAdapter.clear(); 
arrayAdapter.addAll(arrayListOfCities);
arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); 
mDrawerList.invalidateViews();
mDrawerList.forceLayout();
mDrawerList.refreshDrawableState();
```

but it doesn't seem to work, ie the list of planets doesn't get replaced by a list of cities.

Is my approach correct?, and if so, how do I get the list to refresh?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> **Replace the ListView**

There's really no need for that.

---

> **Keep the ListView, but replace its ArrayAdapter**

This would be the easiest to implement. First, add the following string arrays (city names) to res/values/strings.xml:

```
<string-array name="mercury_array">
    <item>Undiscovered City 1 (Mercury)</item>
    <item>Undiscovered City 2 (Mercury)</item>
    <item>Undiscovered City 3 (Mercury)</item>
    <item>Undiscovered City 4 (Mercury)</item>
</string-array>
<string-array name="venus_array">
    <item>Undiscovered City 1 (Venus)</item>
    <item>Undiscovered City 2 (Venus)</item>
    <item>Undiscovered City 3 (Venus)</item>
    <item>Undiscovered City 4 (Venus)</item>
</string-array>
<string-array name="earth_array">
    <item>New York</item>
    <item>Hong Kong</item>
    <item>New Delhi</item>
    <item>London</item>
</string-array>
<string-array name="mars_array">
    <item>Undiscovered City 1 (Mars)</item>
    <item>Undiscovered City 2 (Mars)</item>
    <item>Undiscovered City 3 (Mars)</item>
    <item>Undiscovered City 4 (Mars)</item>
</string-array>
<string-array name="jupiter_array">
    <item>Undiscovered City 1 (Jupiter)</item>
    <item>Undiscovered City 2 (Jupiter)</item>
    <item>Undiscovered City 3 (Jupiter)</item>
    <item>Undiscovered City 4 (Jupiter)</item>
</string-array>
<string-array name="saturn_array">
    <item>Undiscovered City 1 (Saturn)</item>
    <item>Undiscovered City 2 (Saturn)</item>
    <item>Undiscovered City 3 (Saturn)</item>
    <item>Undiscovered City 4 (Saturn)</item>
</string-array>
<string-array name="uranus_array">
    <item>Undiscovered City 1 (Uranus)</item>
    <item>Undiscovered City 2 (Uranus)</item>
    <item>Undiscovered City 3 (Uranus)</item>
    <item>Undiscovered City 4 (Uranus)</item>
</string-array>
<string-array name="neptune_array">
    <item>Undiscovered City 1 (Neptune)</item>
    <item>Undiscovered City 2 (Neptune)</item>
    <item>Undiscovered City 3 (Neptune)</item>
    <item>Undiscovered City 4 (Neptune)</item>
</string-array>
```

Create a method `loadContentList(int)`in `MainActivity`. This is the method that will be called on item click for the main list:

```
private void loadContentList(int position) {

    setTitle(mPlanetTitles[position]);

    String[] content;

    switch(position) {
    case 0:
            content = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.mercury_array);
            break;
    case 1:
            content = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.venus_array);
            break;
    case 2:
            content = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.earth_array);
            break;
    case 3:
            content = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.mars_array);
            break;
    case 4:
            content = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.jupiter_array);
            break;
    case 5:
            content = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.saturn_array);
            break;
    case 6:
            content = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.uranus_array);
            break;
    case 7:
            content = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.neptune_array);
            break;
    default:
            content = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.neptune_array);     
}

    // Change ListView's adapter    
    mDrawerList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            R.layout.drawer_list_item, content));

    // Change OnItemClickListener // CityItemClickListener is defined below
    mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new CityItemClickListener());
}
```

Since we want to update the ListView when a planet item is clicked, we will change the method body of DrawerItemClickListener and call the newly added `loadContentList(int)`:

```
/* The click listner for ListView in the navigation drawer */
private class DrawerItemClickListener implements ListView.OnItemClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        //selectItem(position);
        loadContentList(position);
    }
}
```

We will need another OnItemClickListener to change fragments when a city is clicked. :

```
private class CityItemClickListener implements ListView.OnItemClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

        // This is the method that was being called on planet click 
        // in the original example. Implementation of it is up to you
        selectItem(position);
    }
}
```

---

> **Keep the ListView and the ArrayAdapter, but replace the adapter's data**

Define the ArrayAdapter:

```
private ListView mDrawerList;
private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;    
---------> private ArrayAdapter<String> mAdapter;
```

In MainActivity's onCreate(Bundle):

```
ArrayList<String> planetList = new ArrayList<String>();

planetList.addAll(Arrays.asList(mPlanetTitles));

mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            R.layout.drawer_list_item, planetList);

// set up the drawer's list view with items
mDrawerList.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

We have to pass an ArrayList to avoid `UnsupportedOperationException` when calling `mAdapter.clear()`.

Change `loadContentList(int)` to the following:

```
private void loadContentList2(int position) {

    setTitle(mPlanetTitles[position]);

    String[] content;

    switch(position) {

        ....
        ....
    }

    ArrayList<String> cityList = new ArrayList<String>();

    cityList.addAll(Arrays.asList(content));

    mAdapter.clear();

    mAdapter.addAll(cityList);

    // update
    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();        

    // Change on item click listener
    mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new CityItemClickListener());

}
```

The CityItemClickListener and DrawerItemClickListener will stay the same as before. The only change is: we're not creating a new ArrayAdapter on planet list item click.

You'll need to figure out a way (a button perhaps) for the user to go back to planet list from city view.

I would also suggest that you look into ExpandableListView. It might solve your problem more elegantly.

Comment: Many thanks. it turns out my code was working after all, I was just addAll()ing the wrong string array. Duh!! Thanks for the pointer to ExpandableListView. I had originally dismissed using ExpandableListView as there are circumstances where I want to call the city list directly, ie, without navigating via a list of planets. However, as you rightly pointed out, my approach creates the problem of navigating back from city to planet, which is solved within ExpandableListView. So I've ended up using ExpandableListView  and then a separate ListView for City where appropriate. Thanks again.

Comment: @pinoyyid Actually, navigating back from cities to planets isn't that big a problem. You can add a button that is only visible when a city list is being displayed. On click, reset the adapter to hold `mPlanetTitles` and refresh the ListView. Still, an ExpandableListView would suit your app's need better. If the number of cities is quite large, you can even use a GridView (with 2 columns) to display the cities, and a ListView to display the planets.